# Absolute z-order (across several DataTemplates)

Tags: wpf, z-index, z-order

Ive a ListBox with a Canvas ItemsPanel that displays 2 different types of objects: NodeVMs and LinkLineVMs (using a CompositeCollection).  Each VM object has a DataTemplate:
NodeVMs DataTemplate has a `TextBlock` (A)
LinkLineVMs DataTemplate has a `Line` (B) and a `TextBlock` (C) 
How get the following absolute z-order: A (top), C, B (bottom).

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type p:NodeVM}">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock ... />
                ...
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type p:NetworkLinkVM}">
            <Grid>
                <Line ... />
                <TextBlock ... />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.Resources>
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas IsItemsHost="True" PreviewMouseUp="network_visualization_list_PreviewMouseUp" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
<ListBox>
```

Someone once said a picture is worth a 1000 words.  Green rectangle == NodeVM, Line+small box == NetworkLinkVM.  A is ok as link [-30] passes over other link BUT B is a problem as link [-31] box is hidden BELOW link [-32]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Set your ZIndex index in `ListBox.ItemContainerStyle` instead of your DataTemplate.

The reason for this is that all items are wrapped in a `ListBoxItem`, so you need to set the ZIndex on the `ListBoxItem` instead of on the `DataTemplate`

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="Canvas.ZIndex" 
            Value="{Binding Converter={StaticResource GetObjectZIndexConverter}}" />
</Style>
```

You'll need a converter that checks the `typeof` your databound object, and returns the correct ZIndex based on if it's a `NodeVM` or `NetworkLinkVM`.

This will only set the ZIndex for your DataTemplates, but once those are sorted out, you can set the ZIndex of `NetworkLinkVM's` internal `Line` and `TextBlock`

Comment: Thanks for input - I thought your solution was good - but unfortunately there is still an issue.  Ive posted an image that helps explain situation it better.  Ive got your converter in place that puts all NodeVMs (green) ontop - thats good.  But there is still an issue with the order of the items in the list box effecting zorder.  Although in DataTemplate the link box is above the link line a line+box later in the list is still over a box from a line earlier in the list.  Any ideas most appreciated!

Comment: @Ricibob Hrrm I see what you're saying. Any chance you could separate out your Line objects into a different layer so that all 3 of your objects (Green boxes, blue boxes, and lines) exist in the same Collection, instead of having the blue boxes and lines share a place in the collection?

Comment: Yes that a possible solution but unfortunately not very practical.  The collections are nodes and links - its just going to make a mess of things to break the link strengths (the boxes) out of NetworkLinksVM just for z-order.  I think there is cleanish solution possible - just need to find it!!

Comment: @Ricibob You could try placing two versions of the ListBox on top of each other, with the bottom version only drawing the lines, and the top version only drawing the boxes.

Comment: What I need is to set Canvas.ZIndex on each DataTemplate item.  How to access the ItemsPanel Canvas from within the ListBoxItems DataTemplate? Its late here - Im going to think about it over the weekend.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Ricibob That is not possible. If you open your application using a tool such as Snoop, you'll see that each DataTemplate item exists in a different part of the Visual Tree. I don't know of an easy way to adjust the ZIndex of items that are not part of the same visual tree, however I do know you can place two transparent ListBoxes (I would actually recommend an ItemsControl) on top of eachother, and have the bottom one draw only the lines while the top one draws only the boxes.

Comment: PS You can download Snoop from http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/ It's a great tool for debugging WPF applications