# Access ItemsPanel property from DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, datatemplate, z-index, z-order

In the context of a ListBox with Canvas ItemsPanel I need to access Cavas.ZIndex for each control within the multiple DataTemplates (the list displays several object types).  Its not enough to use a

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Setter Property="Canvas.ZIndex" ..... />
```

as there are several data templates each with several controls and I would like to control the absolute zindex of each control.
Is this even possible?

Comment: Can anyone confirm that this is not possible?

Comment: This is the down side of WPF.  You can do a load of complicated stuff in a couple of lines of XAML - but then something simple like setting an absolution z-order becomes a mega ordeal...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, this is not possible

The reason is that when a ListBox renders, it renders like this (assuming you're referring to the same code you had in [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7931134/302677)):

```
<Canvas>
    <ListBoxItem>
        <ContentPresenter>
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock />
                <Line />
            </Grid>
        </ContentPresenter>
    </ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>
        <ContentPresenter>
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock />
                <Line />
            </Grid>
        </ContentPresenter>
    </ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>
        <ContentPresenter>
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock />
                <Line />
            </Grid>
        </ContentPresenter>
    </ListBoxItem>
    ...
</Canvas>
```

As you can see, each ListBoxItem is rendered as a group of nested controls. You cannot have all your TextBlocks drawn on top of all your Lines because they do not all share the same parent, and ZIndex is used to order items that are within the same parent container.

A workaround would be to use two separate ItemsControls drawn on top of each other. So all your Lines would be drawn on the Bottom ItemsControl while all the TextBlocks would be drawn on the Top ItemsControl.

```
<Grid>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyData}"
                  ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource MyLineTemplate}" />

    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyData}"
                  ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource MyTextBlockTemplate}" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: I am afraid that you are right :-(  - I just wanted to double check in case someone came up with a magic work around... The double list/itemscontrol solution is going to mess up some other code - not sure if it feasable.

Comment: Maybe there is a code behind approach? Or will that suffer the same issue?

Comment: @Ricibob It doesn't matter if you set the ZIndex in code-behind, the controls will still belong to different parents so ZIndex will not get applied. What is the problem with using double ItemsControls?

Comment: The problem with the double items control is that currently I have two object view models NodeVM (the box) and LinkLineVM (the line plus small link stregth box).  I have to then split the link line and put part of it (the box) in one control with the nodes and the other part (the line) by itself in another control.  It would work - its just not that elegant.